# Nested arrays in Avro

Tags: python, arrays, avro

I would like to store two-dimensional arrays of numbers in Avro.
I have tried the following:

```
{
    "namespace": "com.company",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "MyName",
    "doc" : "...",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "MyArray",
            "type": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": {"type": "array","items": "int"}
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I tried to read it with the parser:

```
import avro.schema

schema = avro.schema.parse(open("my_schema.avsc", "r").read())
```

I get the following error:

```
avro.errors.SchemaParseException: Type property "{'type': 'array', 'items': {'type': {'type': 'array', 'items': 'int'}}}" 
not a valid Avro schema: Items schema ({'type': {'type': 'array', 'items': 'int'}}) not 
a valid Avro schema: Undefined type: {'type': 'array', 'items': 'int'} 
(known names: dict_keys(['com.algoint.ecg_frame_file.EcgFrameFile']))
```

Comment: Any 2d NxN list can be represented as a linear array with modulo access

Comment: Its also possible to declare the Avro attribute type as "bytes" and then use the numpy `array.tobytes()` operation to just store the array as bytes.

Comment: Sure, but that defeats the purpose of having an array of integers, and you don't need numpy to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have one too many `type` keys.

You schema should be this instead:

```
{
    "namespace": "com.company",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "MyName",
    "doc" : "...",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "MyArray",
            "type": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {"type": "array","items": "int"}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @Hephaestus Avro is open source. Feel free to contribute to the docs