# How to write numpy array to avro file?

Tags: python, numpy, avro

I want to write a numpy array to an avro file. Here's an small example of the numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
import random
np_array = np.zeros((4,3), dtype=np.float32)
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(3):
            np_array[i, j] = random.gauss(0, 1)
print(np_array)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.6490377   0.29544145 -1.109375  ]
 [ 1.0881975  -0.39123887 -0.36691198]
 [-1.2226632   0.8332004   0.2686829 ]
 [ 1.5417658   0.4520132  -0.03081623]]
```

For my use case the numpy array has 5 million rows and 128 columns, so if possible I want to write the array directly to avro without spending memory converting it to a dictionary and/or Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/74689640/3275464

Comment: The accepted answer for that question recommends using schema type "record". Wouldn't I have to convert the numpy array to a dictionary to make that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question! This solution writes a 2D numpy array to avro without any conversions.

```
import numpy as np
import random
np_array = np.zeros((4,3), dtype=np.float32)
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(3):
        np_array[i, j] = random.gauss(0, 1)
print(np_array)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.6490377   0.29544145 -1.109375  ]
 [ 1.0881975  -0.39123887 -0.36691198]
 [-1.2226632   0.8332004   0.2686829 ]
 [ 1.5417658   0.4520132  -0.03081623]]
```

```
import fastavro
schema_dict = {
    "doc": "test",
    "name": "test",
    "namespace": "test",
    "type": "array",
    "items": "float"
}
schema = fastavro.parse_schema(schema_dict)
with open(<filepath>, "wb") as f:
    fastavro.writer(f, schema, np_array)

with open(<filepath>, "rb") as f:
    reader = fastavro.reader(f)
    for record in reader:
        print(record)
```

Output:

```
[ 0.6490377   0.29544145 -1.109375  ]
[ 1.0881975  -0.39123887 -0.36691198]
[-1.2226632   0.8332004   0.2686829 ]
[ 1.5417658   0.4520132  -0.03081623]
```